# A Feedforward Neural Network (FNN) implemented with RMSProp optimization is exhibiting a tendency to overclassify instances into one particular class

Tags: gradient-descent, feedforward-neural-networks, rust

hope you're alright.

I'm coding an FNN in Rust using the [nalgebra crate](https://crates.io/crates/nalgebra). I coded the backpropagation based on [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/backpropagation/#:%7E:text=criterion%20is%20met.-,The%20Backpropagation%20Algorithm,-Using%20the%20terms) from Brilliant (the link directly highlights the formulas' section I).

## The issue

My network tends to overclassify one class. See logs of some iterations:

```
Pred: [0.4957141833444244, 0.5042858166555757] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.1159099292782023, 0.8840900707217978] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.49812391110550713, 0.5018760888944928] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.785823559592914, 0.21417644040708617] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(0) Loss: 1.7553771084566945  accuracy: 75%
 Pred: [0.921104553204082, 0.07889544679591799] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.43669346100767914, 0.5633065389923209] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.8390020708741205, 0.16099792912587946] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9358457093202687, 0.0641542906797313] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(1) Loss: 2.5487814857735516  accuracy: 75%
 Pred: [0.9938891101436632, 0.0061108898563368074] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.8117580010095468, 0.18824199899045324] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9637103688436267, 0.03628963115637338] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9836993037515837, 0.01630069624841633] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(2) Loss: 5.008814788847665  accuracy: 50%
 Pred: [0.9995224418411457, 0.0004775581588542201] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.9640882324687131, 0.03591176753128681] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9940401356203591, 0.005959864379640862] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9967080323177023, 0.0032919676822977125] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(3) Loss: 8.453172874424054  accuracy: 50%
 Pred: [0.9999695301335619, 3.0469866438138036e-5] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.9955011694391566, 0.004498830560843456] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9993378187078414, 0.0006621812921585512] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9995329830642827, 0.00046701693571723986] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(4) Loss: 12.724406571994546  accuracy: 50%
 Pred: [0.9999986403638063, 1.3596361937582465e-6] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.9996152538707804, 0.0003847461292195687] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9999496312441125, 5.036875588738215e-5] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9999544427172501, 4.5557282750020274e-5] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(5) Loss: 17.759113261749448  accuracy: 50%
 Pred: [0.9999999567632185, 4.323678145397258e-8] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
 Pred: [0.9999768122330864, 2.3187766913582424e-5] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9999973081629956, 2.6918370044323987e-6] Exp: [0.0, 1.0]
 Pred: [0.9999969459673318, 3.054032668285032e-6] Exp: [1.0, 0.0]
(6) Loss: 23.497175499984603  accuracy: 50%
```

This also happens when I have more classes, using other datasets (like the MNIST hand-digits).

## My implementation

Based on the Brilliant article I coded a matrix based implementation of the Backpropagation, i.e. all calculations are made matrix-wise. I do not see any problems with my implementation. I also coded the RMSProp which seems to be fine since when I remove it and only use SGD to train the networks the same issue happens.

**If you want to take a look at the [whole project](https://github.com/thiago-buarqque/NeuraRust/tree/stackoverflow-question), I created a branch, which is a copy of the current main branch, that I'll never delete for the sake of this question.**

## What I tried

1. Checked every activation and loss function I have coded (see my [functions module code](https://github.com/thiago-buarqque/NeuraRust/tree/stackoverflow-question/src/functions)). I'm using sigmoid for the hidden layer and softmax for the output layer. But even if I use relu for the hidden layer the issue is the same.
2. Applied the math by hand, it seems to be check (I'm not an expert at math at all).
3. Remove the RMSProp, just used SGD, same issue the network doesn't learn.
4. Use the Relu activation function for the hidden layer.

## Question

1. In theory, what could cause this?

Comment: Hi @Evry and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! Thank you so much for detailing what you have tried. This is an excellent question, and we hope to see more of your questions on this site soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you initializing the weights of each layer? It turns out that weight initialization plays a surprisingly large part in the network's ability to learn, but these issues are abstracted away in libraries `torch`. I wonder if that could be an issue here. See [this paper](https://paperswithcode.com/method/he-initialization)

Comment: This was the issue. I found out 14 hours ago when heading home. Got myself thinking about the weights initialization. Some time along the way I changed the weight initialization for some technique I do not recall the name of. It probably had some bug or wasn't appropriate. Just initialized between -0.5 and 0.5. But why does the initialization have so much impact on learning?

Comment: Initializing the weights between -0.5 and 0.5 works fine

Comment: Poor initialization can cause exploding or vanishing gradients - it's possible in your case that your network simply didn't learn anything because your gradient norms were too small. The reason I'm guessing that is because your network predicted only one class, which is typically what happens with randomly initialized networks

Comment: I see. Good to know that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Of course - honestly I am not an expert on the dynamics of model initialization. But a good paper is the Kaiming one I linked (that was huge for getting models to learn consistently) as well as Xavier init.

Comment: That is a good recommendation, I'll take a deeper look at the paper, thanks